# C# Multiple CheckBox in one GroupBox for two different Lists

Tags: c#, winforms

I have multiple checkBox inside a GroupBox.

[image: Pic]

The subject is the combination from Grade1 student and Grade 2 student.
The reason I put all the checkbox in one groupbox because the difference between the subjects with the Grade 1 Student and Grade 2 Student is Art and Music only.

When I click on the 'ART' checkbox and 'MUSIC' checkbox, I want it add into the Grade 2 Student List only since Grade 1 student don't have these two course. Although it is clicked, it should not add into Grade 1 Student list.

```
            List<string> checkedGrade1Subject = new List<string>(); 
            List<string> checkedGrade2Subject = new List<string>();

            foreach (CheckBox c in groupBoxSubject.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
            {
                if (c.Checked == true)
                {
                    checkedGrade1Subject.Add(c.Text);
                    checkedGrade2Subject.Add(c.Text);                   
                }
            }
```

Is it possible to do in this way? If so, how I can continue with code above or it is better to have separate groupbox for Grade 1 Students and Grade 2 Students?

Comment: how do you come to know that if Grade 1 or Grade 2 student using this?

Comment: do you have any StudentId ,UserID or anything?

Comment: This sounds like you are putting the cart before the horse. If the code displays check boxes that are not available to a particular Grade group, then why show them? You are trying to fix a problem YOU created. Don’t show the non-valid check boxes for that particular group… problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

for Grade 1 Student  'ART' and 'MUSIC' checkboxes will be Disabled for other Grades like Grade 2 it will be enabled

```
 Grade 1 Student

 ChkMusic.Enabled = false;
 ChkArt.Enabled = false;

 Grade 2 Student

 ChkMusic.Enabled = true;
 ChkArt.Enabled = true;
```